# Problem in understanding this claim from book "Topics in Galois Theory" by Serre.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, galois-theory

Suppose we have a group $G$, and we embed it in $S_{n}$, one defined a $G-$ action on the field $\mathbb{Q}(X_{1},...,X_{n})=\mathbb{Q}(\underline{X})$. Let $E$ be the fixed field under this action. Then $\mathbb{Q}(\underline{X})$ is a Galois extension of $E$ with Galois group $G$.

Then he claims that In geometric terms, the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\underline{X})$ of $E$ corresponds to the projection of varieties: $$\pi: A^{n}\longrightarrow A^{n}/G$$ where $A^{n}$ is affine $n-$sapce over $\mathbb{Q}$

I have difficulty in understanding the above claim. From where varieties came into the picture ? I did not understand the geometric part.

Comment: The point is $G$ not only acts on $\mathbb{Q}(X)$, but also on $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, the polynomial ring in $n$ variables, which is the ring of polynomial functions on $\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{Q}}$. Does this clarify?

Comment: @Mohan can you explain in more detail.

Comment: If my hint did not clarify, I am afraid I will have to know more precisely what you know.

Comment: @Mohan Currently I am reading chapter 1 of Robin Hartshorne's book of Algebraic Geometry to build my basics. Serre's book assumes that reader know algebraic geometry.

Comment: I suggest you read more of Hartshorne and then come back to this issue.

Comment: @Mohan Kindly mention the section of Hartshorne, that will help in understanding this concept. If you have some other reference in mind that discuss the above, Can you please share it with me.

Answer (score 1):

The field $\mathbb Q(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ is the field of rational functions on the variety $\mathbb A^n$, and taking invariants on the field side corresponds to taking quotients on the variety side.

In general, the reason people study f.g. , but non-algebraic, field exts. --- like $\mathbb Q(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ as an extension of $\mathbb Q$ --- is that they arise as the rational function fields of varieties.   Even if you are more interested in the field theory then in the geometry, the connection between f.g. field extensions and varieties is a very powerful tool for visualizing, and even proving, facts about these field extensions.

Comment: I want to read more about it, in detail. Kindly mention some reference.